# Discord.py не выводит список пользователей

Tags: python

```
@bot.command( pass_context = True )
@commands.has_permissions(administrator = True)
async def upload(ctx):
    for guild in bot.guilds:
        for member in guild.members:
            print(f'{member.name} - {member.id}')
```

Выводит только имя и id бота

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте `discord.client.get_all_members()`, чтобы вывести весь список пользователей.

Оно равносильно этому:

```
for guild in client.guilds:
    for member in guild.members:
        print(member)
```

Подробнее - [[Discord.py] - get_all_members()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=guild#discord.Client.get_all_members)

**UPDATE:**
Discord ввел Intents. Это радикальное изменение в том, как пишутся боты. Намерение в основном позволяет боту подписаться на определенные сегменты событий. События, соответствующие каждому намерению, документируются в отдельном атрибуте документации намерений.

И еще вам нужно подтвердить намерения для получения members(intents):

```
import discord
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True  # Subscribe to the privileged members intent.
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

Подробнее об этом - [intents](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html) (Введены с 1.5 Discord.py, когда Discord ужесточил правила)

**UPDATE:** Связи с большой нагрузкой на шлюзы, теперь Discord требует подтвердить намерения для использования данных.

**Чтобы ваш бот мог получить список участников надо :**

1. зайди в discord.com/developers
2. выбрать свое App
3. зайди в раздел Bot
4. Прокрутить до Privileged Gateway Intents и включить там два пункта.

[image: DISCORD]

Comment: Метод все равно возвращает только самого бота, больше никого, но при этом на сервере находятся и другие участники

Comment: @Юрий а права у бота есть? Чтобы он мог видеть всех.

Comment: Да, до 26 октября всё работало, а после он перестал видеть участников, также функция on_member_join теперь не работает

Comment: @Юрий А какую версию Discord.py вы используете?

Comment: @Юрий Нашел решение проблемы, чекайте ответ.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло)